# jQuery: go to URL with target="_blank"

Tags: jquery, url, href, target

I am using this bit of jQuery code to get href of the link:

```
var url = $(this).attr('href');
```

-- and this bit of code to go to that href:

```
window.location = url;
```

Everything is just the way I want it, except the new page opens in the same window as the previous one, and I want it to open in a new window or tab (something that in plain html would have been achieved by using target="_blank" formula).

**Question: How can I open the href in the new window or tab with jQuery?**

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You need to open a new window:

```
window.open(url);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open

Comment: Thank you. That's just what I needed. Another quick question: is there a way to tell the browser to open a new tab rather than a new window?

Comment: I believe it depends upon how the browser is configured (i.e. a setting to open pop-ups in tabs or windows).

Answer (score 75):

Use,

```
var url = $(this).attr('href');
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

**Update**:the `href` is better off being retrieved with prop since it will return the full url and it's slightly faster.

```
var url = $(this).prop('href');
```

Answer (score 10):

> **Question: How can I open the href in the new window or tab with**
>   jQuery?

```
var url = $(this).attr('href').attr('target','_blank');
```

Answer (score 4):

The `.ready` function is used to insert the attribute once the page has finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("class name or id a.your class name").attr({"target" : "_blank"})
})
```

Comment: Just a heads-up for future readers: I was using `jQuery("a").prop("target", "_blank");` without enclosing it in `$document.ready` and it wasn't working in Chrome, but once I enclosed it in the `$document.ready()` call, it started working.

Answer (score 4):

Detect if a target attribute was used and contains "_blank". For mobile devices that don't like "_blank", this is a reliable alternative.

```
    $('.someSelector').bind('touchend click', function() {

        var url = $('a', this).prop('href');
        var target = $('a', this).prop('target');

        if(url) {
            // # open in new window if "_blank" used
            if(target == '_blank') { 
                window.open(url, target);
            } else {
                window.location = url;
            }
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the popup window through jQuery then you'll need to use a plugin.  This one seems like it will do what you want:

http://rip747.github.com/popupwindow/

Alternately, you can always use JavaScript's [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) function.

Note that with either approach, the new window must be opened in response to user input/action (so for instance, a click on a link or button).  Otherwise the browser's popup blocker will just block the popup.

Comment: Thank you. No, not a pop-up. Just a normal window. Normally I would just let html do the job, but a prior bit of code I use in the same menu disables the default behavior for all the links.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[@href^='http']").attr('target','_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 url='/controller/action';  
 window.open(location.origin+url,'_blank');
```