# open new tab in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need some help for href link open to new tab in jquery. I getting the following resuts for, if am click following link  Pay now i get the results from RtObject.ReturnVal.my results success get the following results displayed in new tab.
    $(function () {
            $("#OrderTable > tbody > tr > td> .paynow").click('click', function (Myevent) {

```
            Myevent.preventDefault();

            var passval = $(this).parents().siblings('td:eq(1)').text();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
                async: true,
                url: '/MyAccount/PayNow?OrderId=' + passval,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (RtObject) {
                    //alert(RtObject.isError);
                    //alert(RtObject.CId);
                    if (!RtObject.isError) {
                        //alert(RtObject.isError);
                        if (RtObject.CId == 1) {
                            var newwin;
                            if (newwin && !newwin.closed) {
                                newwin.focus();

                            } else {


                                $(this).target = "_blank";

                                window.location = RtObject.ReturnVal;


                            }
                        }
                        else if (RtObject.CId == -1) {
                            jAlert(RtObject.Message, "Failure");
                        }
                    }
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    jAlert("Cant go to payment process", "Failure");
                }
            });

        });
```

please help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: go to URL with target="\_blank"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673473/jquery-go-to-url-with-target-blank)

Answer (score 0):

Instead `window.location = RtObject.ReturnVal`; use `window.open(RtObject.ReturnVal, '_blank');`

Comment: Hi Viktor, I used that code also but its asking for popup Blocked. i need open new tab without asking for popup blocked.

Comment: @White then you'll use this function
`function openInNewTab(link) {
 var element = document.createElement('a');
 element.target = '_blank';
 element.style.display = 'none';
 element.href = link;
 element.className += 'linkOnNewTab';
 element.click();
}`
for example `openInNewTab(RtObject.ReturnVal);` instead `window.location = RtObject.ReturnVal;`

Comment: Hi, var element = document.createElement('a');
                                    element.target = '_blank';
                                    element.style.display = 'none';
                                    element.href = RtObject.ReturnVal;
                                    element.className += RtObject.ReturnVal;
                                    element.click(); but again asking for popup blocked.

Comment: <a class="paynow"  href="#">Pay now</a> if we are click pay now button. its open new tab.