# Use CTRL or CMD key to open new tab with JS links

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've added some JS links to container divs on a WordPress website. This looks for any link within the container class and makes the entire div clickable. It works great except you can't control or command-click the divs in order to open a new tab. They just open in the same tab.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(function($){
$(".entire-div-products-led-sign-link").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
});
}); </script>
```

Can someone help me figure out how to make these links open in a new tab using both the command (mac) and control (windows) keys?

Comment: Could be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673473/jquery-go-to-url-with-target-blank

Comment: I only want it opening in a new tab via the control or command key like a normal link. Otherwise, I want it to open in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `window.open(url);` instead of `window.location`

Comment: It should be something like this:`if (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) return;` but i'm not sure how to integrate it in the above code.